# Aggregated Function over VLookup on Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, vlookup

Is there a way to get a maximum value of a range of values using standard Excel functions?

**More Info**

- I want to find the maximum value in a range of cells.  **A1:** `=max(A2:A10)`
- However, I don't want to find the max of the value in the cells themselves, but rather of an associated set of values obtained by doing a vlookup on those cells.  i.e. **B2:** `=vlookup(A2,MyLookupName,2,false)` (copy B2 formula down to B10).  **A1:** `=max(B2:B10)`.
- Rather than having to do this in 2 steps (i.e. doing the vlookup in column B, then doing the max over that in cell A1) I'd rather have a single formula which applied both steps in one, in the same cell.  i.e. **A1:** `{=max(vlookup(A2:A10,MyLookupName,2,false))}`

However, this last formula doesn't work, as the VLOOKUP function only accepts a single cell for the `Lookup_Value` parameter; if a range is passed, it takes the top left cell from that range.

**VBA Solution**

To better illustrate the functionality I'm after, I've coded a VBA worksheet function which would do what I'm after; however I'm trying to avoid custom macros.

```
Public Function MaxVLookup(ByRef Lookup_Array As Range, ByRef Table_Array As Range, Col_Index_Num As Long) As Variant
    Dim v As Variant, temp As Variant, max As Variant
    max = Null
    For Each v In Lookup_Array
        temp = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(v, Table_Array, Col_Index_Num, False)
        If IsNull(max) Then
            max = temp
        Else
            If max < temp Then
                max = temp
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MaxVLookup = max
End Function
```

[image: Example Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in A are in the Reference Area only once then you can use SUMUIF() wrapped in a MAX() as an array formula:

```
=MAX(SUMIF(D:D,A1:A10,E:E))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

If they are multiples and you want only the first like VLOOKUP, use LOOKUP():

```
=MAX(IFERROR(LOOKUP(A1:A10,D1:D13,E1:E13),-1E+99))
```

Again this is an array formula.

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

**Screenshot based on example**

[image: Screehshot based on example]

Answer (score 0):

NB: I found an alternate solution to my issue. Since I only needed to map each value to a number, I was able to fake the VLookup by using Match.

i.e. **A1:** `{=max(6-match(A2:A10,MyLookupName,0))}`.

The `6-` is simply to change the value returned by match (i.e. the position of the element I'm looking for in the `MyLookupName` list of values) to the value I'm mapping to.

**Demo Screenshot**

Solution with Values:

[image: Solution with values]

Solution with Formulae:

[image: Solution with Formulae]

---

NB: I've not marked this an an answer, since though it resolved my problem, it doesn't solve all problems of this type / bypasses the answer to the question I'd asked.